# How can I tell which namespace the compiler thinks a function is in?

Tags: namespaces, g++

I'm attempting to deal with an error message produced by g++, regarding the specialization of a template member function in a particular class. I get the error message

```
error: specialization of ‘template<class T> std::vector<T>& push::GrammarEnv::stack_accessor()’ in different namespace [-fpermissive]
```

However, the specialization appears to be in the same namespace. Indeed, changing the namespace produces an error stating that the template function was not declared.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I tell what namespace the compiler believes the specialization is taking place in? The error message simply gives the original, unspecialized function declaration's namespace.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? GCC 4.7 did made significant progresses on such issues... And future GCC 4.8 (i.e. the current GCC trunk) even more...

Comment: I've got 4.6, and unfortunately, am not able to do a unilateral upgrade.

Comment: You might temporarily use `g+-4.7` (or perhaps LLVM/Clang++ 3.2) to understand your issue, then switch back to 4.6 once the problem is solved.